# neo4j how to compare two list and return the different items

Tags: neo4j

I am  using  `neo4j MATCH` and get two list of User: `listA,listB,`
and *listB* is part of *listA*
how can I return users only in *listA* but not in *listB* use **cipher query**
the *cipher* like :

> MATCH listA, listB
>   RETURN listA - listB

Here is my previous question: [neo4j cypher multi relationship between nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779786/neo4j-cypher-multi-relationship-between-nodes)

**Done See solution in the link above**

Comment: The answer you link to may have solved your problem but I don't see how it answers this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To return members of one list that are not in another you can use the `FILTER` function ([docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-collection.html#functions-filter)), for example

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5,6] as listA, [1,2,3] as listB
RETURN FILTER( n IN listA WHERE NOT n IN listB ) as listC

c
4, 5, 6
Returned 1 row in 90 ms
```

Comment: Filter is no longer supported. Please use list comprehension instead

Comment: Filter is no longer supported. Please see a better solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446845/neo4j-filter-function-is-no-longer-supported

Answer (score 3):

Filter function is removed in the latest Neo4j version 4.0 doc [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-4.0) 
instead, use [List comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension)

```
WITH [1,2,3,4,5,6] as listA, [1,2,3] as listB
RETURN [n IN listA WHERE NOT n IN listB] as listC
```

This results in an output 
4, 5, 6