# Neo4j Filter function is no longer supported

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher

I want to compare two lists in order to find the values in the first list which are not in the second and return them. thanks in advance guys 
the code returns:  Filter is no longer supported 
is there any alternative way to do this

```
MATCH (cu:Customer{name: "myCustomer"})-[pu:PURCHASED]->(o:Order)-[*]->(cat:Category)
MATCH (b:Book)-[:IS_a]->(cat)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT pu.ISBN) AS purchasedbooks,COLLECT(DISTINCT b.ISBN) AS booksFromTheSameCategory
RETURN FILTER( n IN booksFromTheSameCategory WHERE NOT n IN purchasedbooks ) as listC
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) syntax instead of the obsolete `filter` function:

```
MATCH (cu:Customer{name: "myCustomer"})-[pu:PURCHASED]->(o:Order)-[*]->(cat:Category)<-[:IS_a]-(b:Book)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT pu.ISBN) AS purchasedbooks, COLLECT(DISTINCT b.ISBN) AS booksFromTheSameCategory
RETURN [n IN booksFromTheSameCategory WHERE NOT n IN purchasedbooks] as listC
```

*You can see Cypher syntax change documentation on [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-4.0).*

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will remember that